# Postgres: string aggregation and concatenation

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.client_code, 
    max(d.created_at) as last_document_created_at, 
    u.brand_id, 
    t.name as template_name, 
    count(d)
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN documents d ON u.id = d.user_id
    INNER JOIN templates t ON t.id = d.template_id
GROUP BY 1, 3, 4
```

Which returns information like this:

```
client_code last_document_created_at    brand_id template_name  count
---------------------------------------------------------------------
client1     2017-12-06 10:03:47 +1100   39       newsletter_r   1
client1     2017-12-05 15:23:24 +1100   39       Other media    5
client2     2017-12-21 17:07:11 +1100   39       newsletter_r   4
client3     2018-01-11 12:10:43 +1100   39       newsletter_r   2
client3     2017-12-06 11:45:21 +1100   39       Other media    1
```

What are my options to concatenate the `template_name` and `count` fields so that each user (represented in `u.client_code`) is on one line? I know I can call `string_agg` the column like so:

```
...
string_agg(distinct t.name, ', ') as template_name, 
...
```

But that of course ruins the respective counts:

```
newsletter_r, Other media   6
```

**Update**

I could do this:

```
string_agg(concat_ws(': ', t.name::text, count(d)::text), ', ') as template_count
```

But that gives me an error:

```
aggregate function calls cannot be nested LINE 5: string_agg(concat_ws(': ', t.name::text, count(d)::text)... ^ : SELECT u.client_code,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you want to format your concatenated field, but have you tried putting your original query into a sub-query and applying a `string_agg` to it?  Something like this:

```
SELECT client_code, STRING_AGG(template_name || template_count, ',') 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        u.client_code, 
        MAX(d.created_at) AS last_document_created_at, 
        u.brand_id, 
        t.name AS template_name, 
        COUNT(d) AS template_count
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN documents d ON u.id = d.user_id
    INNER JOIN templates t ON t.id = d.template_id
    GROUP BY 1, 3, 4
) src
GROUP BY client_code
```

I haven't tested it, so you may have some syntax errors.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: That works pretty well! I don't know how to get the `last_document_created_at`  column through, though, because I'm forced to `group_by` that column which splits `u.client_code` into many rows: `column "src.last_document_created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Well, how do you determine which `last_document_created_at` value to return for each `client_code`?  Or do you just include it in the `string_agg`?

Comment: I just did another `agg`: `(array_agg(last_document_created_at))[1] as last_created`. Done (I think?). Thanks so much!

Comment: Woohoo!  Glad it worked :)  Another option is to apply a MAX -- `MAX(last_document_created_at)`.

Comment: Oh durr, ha. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT u.client_code, 
       max(d.created_at) as last_document_created_at, 
       u.brand_id, 
       string_agg(t.name, ',') as template_name, 
       count(distinct d.id)
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     documents d
     ON u.id = d.user_id INNER JOIN
     templates t
     ON t.id = d.template_id
GROUP BY 1, 3;
```

Comment: There's an error in your `string_agg()` (it takes two arguments). Also this doesn't produce anything different than my query when that's fixed.